# How to detect, in a QWidget, closing the main window

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I know that similar question was already answered, but my case is a little bit different

**Case:**

- I have a QWidget which contains a **QLineEdit** and a **QListWidget**
- The **QListWidget** is a **FramelessWindow** which means that it is not located in the main window but it appears independently *(actually it is a dynamically changing list depending on the content of the QLineEdit filed: "filter as you type")*

**Problems:**

- When I close the **main window**, it will not close the **QListWidget** automatically. After the main window closed, the **QListWidget** will be still seen. - I could not find event, in the QWidget, which would work for that purpose. The closeEvent(self, event) is never triggered.
- When I move the main window the QListWidget will be still stay in the original position. It will not follow the **QLineEdit**'s position. I could not find event, in the QWidget, which would work for that purpose.

**Conditions:**

- I do not want to detect the changes in the main window. I know that the

  > closeEvent(self, event)

  works in the main window, and I could delegate it to the **QListWidget**.

  BUT I want to write an independent widget, which does not depend on the setting in the main window.

Can somebody help me with telling/suggesting how to detect the **window close/window move** inside a widget?

If you need the code (pretty long ~300 lines), I can copy it here.

Comment: But if the closing/moving of the list-widget depends on another widget, it's not actually independant, is it? Anyway, you can use an [event-filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) to monitor events from another widget.

Comment: When I said independent I meant it should work as, for example, the QLabel or QWidget... Using the QLabel/QWidget ..., I do not have to configure anything in the main window related to the QLabel, but it will work OK. It reacts for the moving or resizing of the main window.

Or, for example the QComboBox. This widget has a QListWidget (or similar) and it does not need to be set anything in the main window (just adding it to the layout)

Comment: Anyway, your recommendation -eventFilter- works OK. Thank you very much